# How do i handle polymorphic classes with json and c# without having System.Security.VerificationException error?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, polymorphism

I am trying to create a Wcf Rest service using c#

The idea is to handle transactions/User/cards informations and so I've created the following structure:

```
[DataContract]
public class Result : Response
{
    public List<IObject> data { get; set; }

}
[DataContract]
public class UserData : IObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }

    //...

}
[DataContract]
public class CardData : IObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }

    //...

}
[DataContract]
public class Error : Response
{

    [DataMember]
    public string errorID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}
public abstract class Response
{

}
public abstract class IObject
{

}
public class Status : Response
{ public bool status { get; set; } }
```

The idea is that Cards/users are IObjects and that my Result has a list of them. Then result, status and error would be on the Reponse.
I've create the method to handle the get request and the response

```
public Dictionary<String, Response> GetUsers()
{
    using (var db = new Context())
    {
        try
        {
            var query = from result in db.Users
                        select result;

            List<IObject> r = query.Select(state => new UserData
            {
                id = state.AccountNumber,
                //...
            } as IObject
                    ).ToList();

            Result res = new Result { data = r };
            Dictionary<String, Response> dic = new Dictionary<String, Response> { };
            dic.Add("Error", new Error
            {
                errorID = "0",
                errorMessage = "success"
            });
            dic.Add("Status", new Status { status = true });
            dic.Add("response", res);
            return teste;


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var ErrorMessage = e.Message.ToString();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Although it seems a little messy, iam able to compile it. When I call a get request of getUsers i get the following error:

"An exception of type 'System.Security.VerificationException' occurred in RestService.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Operation could destabilize the runtime."

The ideia of response i wanted was something like:

```
{"status": true,"error": { "errorID" 0,
  "errorMessage": "success"},"result": "GetUsersResult": [ .... ]}
```

I understand this is very sloppy coded, so i ask you the proper way to handle this.

Comment: I ran into similar issues with serializing derived classes etc. My life became much easier when I switched to Newtonsoft.JSON. This setting here solved all my problems: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

Comment: hello, i've tried to use this library but i got my response full of \ . was this supossed to?